# How to display student list in this program in Go language?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct {
    rollnumber int
    name       string
    address    string
}

func NewStudent(rollno int, name string, address string) *Student {
    s := new(Student)
    s.rollnumber = rollno
    s.name = name
    s.address = address
    return s
}

type StudentList struct {
    list []*Student
}

func (ls *StudentList) CreateStudent(rollno int, name string, address string) *Student {
    st := NewStudent(rollno, name, address)
    ls.list = append(ls.list, st)
    return st
}

func main() {
    student := new(StudentList)
    student.CreateStudent(24, "Asim", "AAAAAA")
    student.CreateStudent(24, "Naveed", "BBBBBB")
    fmt.Println(student)
}
```

/* When I run this program it gives addresses in output instead of the values I stored kindly check and let me know how can I display the actual data. I am a newbie in Go*/

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the pointer by dereferencing it:

`fmt.Println(*student)`

But your StudentList.list is an array of pointers to students so you need to derefence those too. My 2 cents, don't use pointers unless you have good reason to.

See your code slightly modified:
https://go.dev/play/p/PkNkUF0EFt7

Comment: I have updated but it is still printing address

Comment: No it prints a list to pointers. You need to dereference each element of that list.

Comment: @ Ado Ren How can you please guide me ?

Comment: Have a look here, I modified a little bit your code: https://go.dev/play/p/PkNkUF0EFt7

Rule of thumb is to not bother with pointer early on and don't create your object with `new` unless you have good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer) on struct `StudentList` to modify the output on `fmt` pkg.

This is the example:

```golang
...
type StudentList struct {
    list []*Student
}
...


func (ls StudentList) String() string {
    var b strings.Builder
    for _, v := range ls.list {
        fmt.Fprintf(&b, "%+v\n", *v)
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

[**playground**](https://go.dev/play/p/G56E411tn2e)